# How to Make Dynamic Query In Triiger In Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-trigger

MY Current Code(Which Is Wrong)

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trg_After_Update] ON [dbo].[PurchaseDetails]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Product SET Rate = I.SallingPrice, 
        --@Result int=0;
        --if(I.Quantity > D.Quantity)
            --@Result = I.Quantity - D.Quantity
            --Stock = Stock - @Result
        --ELSE
            --@Result = D.Quantity - I.Quantity
            --Stock = Stock + @Result
    FROM Inserted I inner join deleted D on I.DetailsID = D.DetailsID
    WHERE ProductID = I.ProductID
END
```

When User Update Purchase Bill Entry, Then First Cheack Whether Old Entry Quantity Is Less Or Greater Than Current Quantity. Then Count Diffrence Between Old And New Quantity
Then Update Record Upon Greater Or Small Quantity And Mines And Plus Using If Condition

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: No `if` needed. Essentially both cases are doing `Stock = Stock - D.Quantity + I.Quantity`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the question, you are looking for something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trg_PurchaseDetails_After_Update] ON [dbo].[PurchaseDetails]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE P 
    SET Rate = I.SallingPrice, 
        Stock = Stock - D.Quantity + I.Quantity
    FROM Product P
    INNER JOIN Inserted I ON P.ProductID = I.ProductID
    INNER JOIN deleted D on I.DetailsID = D.DetailsID
END
```

Comment: This Is C# Expression Which Helps You To Understand Login...                           Stock = (I.Quantity > D.Quantity ? ( Stock - (I.Quantity-D.Quantity)) :  ( Stock + (D.Quantity - I.Quantity)) )

Comment: You could use case for this, but I don't think you should. Would you like me to add the case expression to the answer?

Comment: @SiddiqueBagwan - that's an unnecessarily convoluted way of writing `Stock = Stock - (I.Quantity - D.Quantity);`. If `I.Quantity` is smaller than `D.Quantity` then `I.Quantity - D.Quantity` produces a negative number whose magnitude is exactly equal to `D.Quantity - I.Quantity`. And subtracting a negative number is the same as adding the absolute value of that negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Slight tweaks based on [Zohar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42647610/15498) - we're meant to make stock levels go down based on these purchases, rather than up. But we also need to consider what happens when multiple rows are updated that deal with the same `ProductID`. So we need to do some aggregation as well before applying the update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trg_PurchaseDetails_After_Update] ON [dbo].[PurchaseDetails]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE P 
    SET Rate = I.SallingPrice, 
        Stock = Stock - (I.Quantity - D.Quantity)
    FROM Product P
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT ProductID,SUM(Quantity) as Quantity,
                MAX(SallingPrice) as SallingPrice from Inserted group by ProductID) I
             ON P.ProductID = I.ProductID
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT ProductID,SUM(Quantity) as Quantity from deleted group by ProductID) D
             on P.ProductID = D.ProductID 
END
```

Note also that I've assumed it's correct to take the maximum `SallingPrice` value from all updated values for each product. If that's not correct, we need a clearer specification of what should happen for an update that affects multiple rows with the same `ProductID` value.

As commented below Zohar's answer, your conditional logic is unnecessarily convoluted, since `4 - (5 - 7)` and `4 + (7 - 5)` produce the same result, there's no need to switch around the subtraction inside the brackets and to switch the outer operator.

---

To understand what I'm talking about with the need for aggregation, consider the following script (which uses [Siddique's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42663350/15498)):

```
create table dbo.Product (
    ProductID int not null primary key,
    Stock int not null,
    Rate int not null
)
go
insert into dbo.Product(ProductID,Stock,Rate) values (1,49,5)
go
create table dbo.PurchaseDetails (
    DetailsID int not null primary key,
    ProductID int not null,
    Quantity int not null,
    SallingPrice int not null)
go
insert into dbo.PurchaseDetails (DetailsID,ProductID,Quantity,SallingPrice) values
(1,1,10,5),
(2,1,20,10)
go
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trg_After_Update] ON [dbo].[PurchaseDetails]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Product SET Rate = I.SallingPrice,
    Stock = (CASE
        WHEN I.Quantity > D.Quantity
            THEN (Stock - (I.Quantity - D.Quantity))

        WHEN I.Quantity < D.Quantity
            THEN (Stock + (D.Quantity - I.Quantity))
        END)
    FROM inserted I Inner join deleted D on I.DetailsID = D.DetailsID AND I.ProductID = D.ProductID
    Where Product.ProductID = I.ProductID
END
go
update PurchaseDetails set Quantity = Quantity + 5
go
select * from Product
select * from PurchaseDetails
```

The result is:

```
ProductID   Stock       Rate
----------- ----------- -----------
1           44          10
DetailsID   ProductID   Quantity    SallingPrice
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------
1           1           15          5
2           1           25          10
```

Stock has been adjusted by 5 - but we actually adjusted two rows and the total Stock should have changed by 10, not 5.

Comment: Not a problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trg_After_Update] ON [dbo].[PurchaseDetails]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Product SET Rate = I.SallingPrice,
    Stock = (CASE
        WHEN I.Quantity > D.Quantity
            THEN (Stock - (I.Quantity - D.Quantity))

        WHEN I.Quantity < D.Quantity
            THEN (Stock + (D.Quantity - I.Quantity))
        END)
    FROM inserted I Inner join deleted D on I.DetailsID = D.DetailsID AND I.ProductID = D.ProductID
    Where Product.ProductID = I.ProductID
END



GO
```

Comment: As I tried to point out in my answer, this type of solution (or Zohar's) has a bad problem - if multiple rows are updated that reference the *same* `ProductID`, this `UPDATE` will *not* do what you expect. It will apply one update to the `Product` table (which one is not known) and ignore the others. Also, as people are repeatedly trying to tell you, this conditional logic is *not* necessary. `5 - (-4)` is *already* equal to `5 + 4`, by maths.